# Select all the rows that match the earliest date for a particular matching column

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres (11) database with a table that lists places individuals visited, and the date they visited:

```
name | place |    date
-----+-------+-----------
  Al |     x | 2020-01-01
  Al |     y | 2020-01-01
  Al |     z | 2020-02-02
 Bob |     q | 2020-06-06 
 Bob |     q | 2020-07-07 
 Bob |     r | 2020-07-07 
 Sue |     z | 2020-07-07 
 Sue |     a | 2020-07-07
 Sue |     b | 2020-08-08
```

I want to get all the places that each individual visited on their 'first day' - i.e. all places where the name and date are the same, and it is the earliest date *for that name*. The result would be:

```
name | place |    date
-----+-------+-----------
  Al |     x | 2020-01-01
  Al |     y | 2020-01-01
 Bob |     q | 2020-06-06 
 Sue |     z | 2020-07-07 
 Sue |     a | 2020-07-07
```

Can anyone suggest how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have all the rows in the table `visits`, you can create something like this by first constructing a query that selects the first date that each person visited. This is easily done using:

```sql
SELECT name, MIN(date) AS date FROM visits GROUP BY name
```

Once you have that, you can just join the result of this with the original table. It will then only use the rows that have the the same name and date. I choose to use a CTE, because that is easier to follow:

```sql
WITH 
  first_day AS (SELECT name, MIN(date) AS date FROM visits GROUP BY name)
SELECT name, place, date
  FROM first_day JOIN visits USING (name, date);
```